# Find eigen vectors and eigen spaces or $3 \times 3$ matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hi I'm having trouble finding the eigenvectors of this matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1  & -3 &   3\\
3 & -5 &  3 \\
6 & -6 &  4 \end{bmatrix}$$

I can't seem to simplify the matrix when I do the usual ($\lambda I-A$) calculation?

Also how can I find a basis for each eigen space?

Comment: Have you found the eigenvalues?

Comment: write a vector (a,b,c) and see for what values of $a,b,c$ there exists $\lambda$ such that $A(a,b,c)=\lambda(a,b,c)$ this is ugly 3 equations with 3 variables and 1 parameter..

Comment: Hint: find $\lambda$ so $\det (A - \lambda I) = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
\begin{align}
\det(A-\lambda I)&=\begin{vmatrix}
1-\lambda &-3&3\\3&-5-\lambda&3 \\6&-6 &4-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
-2-\lambda &2 +\lambda & 0\\3&-5-\lambda&3 \\6&-6 &4-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}\\[2ex]
& = \begin{vmatrix}
0 &2-\lambda & 0\\-2 -\lambda&-5-\lambda&3 \\ 0 &-6 &4-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}=(2+\lambda)^2(4-\lambda).
\end{align}
Can you proceed?